# How can I reload the current page in a Webix datatable when using paging?

Tags: javascript, webix

I am currently using Webix 5.3.4, and I am trying to reload a page in a DataTable after updating one of the items. This is the way I got it to work:

```
   let grid = $$("grid");
   grid.clearAll(); // Need to do this
   grid.load(grid.config.url, 'json', function(){
        grid.refresh()
   });
```

However, this cause the entire table to be wiped clear before the new data is loaded. I need to do  `grid.clearAll();` or else only the first page is loaded. **Is there anyway for me to refresh the current page of a datatable without using grid.clearAll() ?**

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`grid.loadNext(20, 60);`

Which will load 20 rows starting from position 60. 
Please be sure that each row has a unique ID, as data without IDs or win non-unique IDs will not be updated correctly.

P.S. Also, in your code grid.refresh is unnecessary, the load command will repaint grid with new data automatically.